# Calling custom directive form controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have written a custom directive to load 3 drop downs and handle the change event of the drop down inside the controller. On change of the dropdown value I am getting the changed value inside my controller function. I need to call my custom directive and pass the new value.

I am new to AngularJs custom directive. Please let me know how to invoke a directive from within the controller.

The view where I render the custom directive:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-header clearfix">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h3 class="no-margin">Search for a Host</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- /page-title -->
  </div>
  <div class="padding-md">
    <div class="hostsFilters row">
        <select ng-model="BU" ng-change="changeTheView()" class="form- control">
            <option value="">BU</option>
            <option value="1">BU1</option>
            <option value="2">BU2</option>
            <option value="3">BU3</option>
            <option value="4">BU4</option>
        </select>
        <span>OR</span>
        <select ng-model="Application" ng-change="changeTheView()" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Application</option>
            <option value="1">App1</option>
            <option value="2">App2</option>
            <option value="3">App3</option>
            <option value="4">App4</option>
        </select>
        <span>OR</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-text" ng-model="hostName.host_name" placeholder="Hostname">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <i-data-grid></i-data-grid>
</div>
```

The code of my controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularFullstackApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.changeTheView=function(){
    console.log('Came inside the Change the view function..');
    //Now invoke the custom directive.
  }
});
```

The code for my directive:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('angularFullstackApp')
  .directive('iDataGrid', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'app/iDataGrid/iDataGrid.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable();
      } );
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: could you add some code what you tried..

Comment: do you want to call those event from iDataGrid iteself or by creating different directive?

Comment: The iDataGrid needs to be invoked from the Controller when there is any change in the dropdown. The controller keeps listening to the changes in the dropdown and where there is a change, the controller need to call the directive and pass the changed value to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a use of attribute, & pass the values inside attribute for which you wanted to place a watch that would fire when any of the value changed

**Markup**

```
<i-data-grid watch-values="['BU', 'Application']"></i-data-grid>
```

**Code**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularFullstackApp')
  .directive('iDataGrid', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'app/iDataGrid/iDataGrid.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable();
        scope.$watch(attrs.watchValues,function(newVal, oldVal){
            //newly changed value available here with same sequence
            //as you passed ['BU', 'Application'] here, it fires fn when any of value changed,
            //newVal[0] contains newly changed value of BU
            //& newVal[1] will contain newly changed value of Application
            //call what ever code on basis of this values
        },true);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But how will i get the changed value for watch-values tag? I understood the directive part but not on the invoking part.

Comment: Can you ping me your gmail id please. That will be better for communication ?

Comment: So there is no need to call the controller's `changeTheView` function?

Comment: @Pradeep you could get rid of that method, you could ping me on my gmail parkarpankaj3@gmail.com